# Handling multiple login methods

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Currently, I'm using Parse to handle my backend, and I have multiple ways to login (via regular email/password and via linkedin).

Parse has a specific method of logging in requiring username/password.

```
PFUser *parseUser = [PFUser logInWithUsername:username password:password];
```

If a user registers through linkedin, I hash a combination of his information as his password, and login through parse. (i.e. username: user's linkedin account / password: hashed version of user information).

If a user registers through email, the user sets his own password, logs in through parse (i.e. username: user's email / password: user's predefined password).

There's no way to retrieve a plain text version of the password, so what would be a good way to handle login through linkedin when the user has registered regularly (set his own password), and vice versa?

Comment: I doubt it's a good idea to use the information of a user's linkedin password to login into your own web service.

Comment: not using linkedin's password (i have no way of obtaining this as I'm using openauth). what I'm doing specifically is hashing the the user's linkedin account, birthday, etc. and a specific passcode key that only I know myself.

Comment: Parse offers login via facebook and twitter as well. Not enough? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Parse has published a tutorial on how to handle third party authentication.

http://blog.parse.com/2014/01/14/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app/
https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app